# Do serious grammarians endorse the "Can I"/"May I" distinction?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

Just now, I wanted to ask a question that was something like, "Can I get a thorough list of all the parts of speech that a sentence can be broken down into?" But then a nagging voice appeared in my head and said, 
"Of course you can! You certainly have the capability -- but that's not what you want, is it." "You're asking for help, so use *may*."

My question is: Should I invariably trust that voice, instilled in students by grammar school teachers everywhere? What do serious linguists and language enthusiasts think about the "Can I"/"May I" distinction?  Would they agree, or is it fair to say that using "can" there has become proper idiomatic English? I ask because I couldn't really think of a quick way to rephrase that sentence using "may", and began to wonder whether it was just another one of those kludgy myths megalomaniac teachers enforce on their students...

Comment: This seems a bit inflammatory with the choice of "serious" in the title. How are you defining a "serious grammarian"? I suspect those grammar school teachers consider themselves serious. Surprisingly, I was unable to find evidence this was a duplicate; I expected someone to have asked this already.

Comment: @MrHen I'm not trying to denigrate anyone.  By "serious" I mean academics or hardcore English enthusiasts. Basically, people who are aware that lots of dogmatic prescriptivist rules are poppycock and are belied by historical usage.

Comment: @Billare: Your clarification is _more_ inflammatory. Do you mean "Do non-prescriptivists endorse ..." I can think of a handful of less aggressive ways to word this question. Why did you choose this one?

Comment: Now now. *Serious linguists* pretty much consigned prescriptive grammarians to the dustbin of history decades ago, and Jason's answer accurately sums up the descriptive position as of now. Mind you, I too am surprised no-one seems to have raised the *may/can* distinction here before - it was always a great favourite amongst pedants everywhere, as I recall.

Comment: I have never met a serious grammarian. Come to think of it, I've never even met a grammarian. We don't allow them in our country.

Comment: @MrHen I apologize if I came off inflammatory in that comment.  All I'm trying to do is differentiate between people with considered, historically aware opinions, and those with reactionary, inappropriately dogmatic opinions.  I'm just using "serious" here as a concise way to say "within the sphere of academia."

Comment: @Billare: Fair enough. For what it's worth, _I_ am not personally offended and don't consider myself a serious grammarian. I hope you get the answer you were looking for. :)

Comment: @Billare: Am I right in reading your question as something like, “In actual usage (as recorded/analysed by academic linguists), does the use of *can* vs. *may* follow any specific pattern?  If so, is this pattern anything like the traditional prescription of the distinction between them?”  Just trying to go for clarification, since though some of the answers so far are interesting, none of them seem to actually address it directly yet…

Comment: @PLL Yes that's exactly it.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know what the hell Robusto's comment is supposed to mean, and I'm not sure I appreciate it on my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Repeating my answer to [this related question,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22258/has-may-become-a-formal-version-of-can/22343) I searched Shakespeare's plays, and found these two examples where it appears that *can* and *may* are used in ways opposite the commonly prescribed *can we/may we* distinction. I don't know when or how this distinction developed or was prescribed, but my conclusion is that it is not a historical feature of English grammar.

From Shakespeare, *Cymbeline,* Act I, Scene 4:

> Can we, with manners, ask what was
>   the difference?

From Shakespeare, *All's Well that Ends Well,* Act I, Scene 1:

> Ay. You have some stain of soldier in
>   you: let me ask you a question. Man is
>   enemy to virginity; how may we
>   barricado it against him?

I think the problem may be that unlike, say, German (which has 
*dürfen*) English doesn't have a modal verb which always means "to be
allowed to". For example, if I say "It may be rainy tomorrow,"
I do not mean that I am permitting the clouds to rain. The modal
verbs *can* and *may* have both been appropriated for this 
meaning in English, but I don't see any clear semantic reason 
for using one rather than the other. Without either a 
semantic reason for or a historical tradition of making this 
distinction, prescriptive grammarians are fighting an uphill battle.

Comment: I think it's less commonly used but: _Es dürfte Regen geben._ = It may rain.

Comment: @z7sg: I didn't know that. Clearly, I should have said *usually* rather than *always* when talking about the meaning of *dürfen*. But my point still holds; for instance, if I said "I may go to the store," it would probably not mean "I am allowed to go to the store."

Comment: I should add, in the interest of honesty, that most of the quotes from Shakespeare with questions involving *can I* or *may I* use them the way that the grammarians prescribe. So there may be some justification for this grammatical distinction, although it appears not to have been a hard and fast rule.

Answer (score 6):

This is a matter of context and style, not some sort of esoteric detail that "serious grammarians" (which I won't dwell on) might idly debate.

In a casual context, use the words "can" and "may" interchangeably with an emphasis on "can" for everyday purposes.

Keep this in mind though: Each of the two words has a distinct meaning. For contracts or the law, this difference is observed. Personal experience for justification: I was with a friend in traffic court in Arizona. Presiding judge had approx 100 cases to rule on, none involving injuries or damage. When he got to my friend's case, he sent the plea agreement back to the Assistant District Attorney, because there was ambiguity due to the use of "may" instead of "shall". "May pay a fine" is an option, a choice, whereas "shall pay a fine" is mandatory.

The judge was presiding over misdemeanor and minor criminal traffic citations in a small town in Arizona, and court was in session for three hours with no break. Yet he noticed an inconsistency in wording with a very quick scan of the paper work, and deemed it important enough to involve the DA's office for five minutes to resolve. So don't dismiss the importance of such distinctions. However, context should be your first criteria, then grammatical "correctness".

Comment: Can you clarify why a difference between the meaning of "may" and "shall" is relevant to a discussion on the difference in meaning between "may" and "can"?

Comment: [@Peter Taylor](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3542/peter-taylor) I was using an example to emphasize why a minor distinction is relevant, due to the situation. Similarity to the question here? "May" versus "can" and "Shall" versus "may": In both cases, there is a difference between free-will versus something exogenous as the determinant of whether the action is completed. For **shall/may**, "shall" is an injunction, there is no choice, but "may" is  optional. For **may/can**, "may" is contingent upon receiving permission, while "can" is within your control, the scope of your ability.

Comment: Your pedantic judge was apparently kicking up over a feasible distinction between *may* and *shall*, not *may* and *can*, so it's not directly relevant. But he was just flexing his puny legal/pseudolinguistic muscles because he could get away with it. The legal meaning of such wording is (within reason) whatever the writer obviously meant, and this principle would be upheld in an appeal to a higher court if necessary. Words are not so important as to *create* the law, they're just what we use to write it down.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well in this case, I was happy about it. It made the difference between my friend going to the payment window in the courthouse and paying $250.00 in cash versus immediately departing the courthouse and going home. That is probably irrelevant. I no longer am sure what is or isn't relevant on this question!

Comment: To be honest, I think nothing is really relevant to this wretched can/may distinction from a *language* point of view. All it's ever been is pedantry that allows us to swap tales of how certain people have misguidedly attempted to force their own prejudices on others. I just meant that whereas in your friend's case it was easier to cave in than to argue the toss, the judge was backed up by ephemeral *might*, not by objective and enduring *right*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Giggle! I just saw your reply, now, 18 months later. It **is** wretched, the can/may distinction. It gets so tedious after the umpteen-millionth time.

Comment: @Feral: If you ask me, *spurious* is probably more accurate than *wretched* in this context (except it fails to convey the utter tedium). I find it particularly heartening that Peter Shor managed to unearth two instances from Shakespeare, showing that the Bard himself was prepared to run directly counter to the so-called distinction. Which, quite frankly, is on a par with that dorky "rule" about not using prepositions to end sentences with. (Though I admit it doesn't work very well in that one! :)

Answer (score 4):

I think a serious descriptive grammarian would tell you what you already know: *can I* is more common and *may I* indicates more formal style, but in this kind of context they mean exactly the same thing.

However that does not tell you which one you *should* use. For that, ask a writer whose style you’d like to emulate; consult a usage guide; or stop worrying about it. :)

Comment: For what it’s worth, other possibilities include *Could I have...* or directly asking *What are all the parts of speech that...?* I think I would go with the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a grammarian, let alone a *serious* one, but I'd like to make a case for both words being synonymous in that context.

Let's look at the following phrase in which a student asks a teacher for permission to go to the bathroom:

> [1]  May I go to the bathroom?
>   [2]  Can I go to the bathroom?

Sentence [1] is pretty self-explanatory.

Sentence [2], though, could be interpreted as follows:

> [2-alt]  If I have your permission to go to the bathroom, then I am able to go.  If I do not have your permission, then I'm not able to go.  Therefore, I could ask: am I able to go to the bathroom?  Or, rather:  can I go the bathroom?

Sentence [2-alt] uses the definition of "can" that means to "be able to."  The student is asking if he or she is able to go to the bathroom.  (if he or she does not have permission, then he or she is not able to go.)  The "with your permission" part was *understood*, if you will.

**edit:** Changed [2-alt] to be slightly more logical and slightly less redundant.  The explanation following it no longer makes as much sense, but I think it still serves its purpose.

Comment: "Can I, with your permission, go to the bathroom" simply and redundantly says,

Comment: [gol dern 5 minute limit!]"Can I, with your permission, go to the bathroom" simply and redundantly says, "Do I have your permission to, with your permission, go to the bathroom". What person, save for those suffering from constipation, does not have the ability to go to the bathroom. "go to the bathroom" can also be interpreted as just visiting the bathroom. Is there also a prescription, given prescriptivists' penchant for clear and unambiguous language, against not honestly describing the real reason for one's visit to the john.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that anyone ever say "Can I, with your permission, go to the bathroom."  That would definitely be redundant.  I only included that parenthetical element to show that one's inability to "use" the bathroom is not the only reason one would not be able to go.  A teacher preventing a student from going to the bathroom would be a reason why someone _cannot_ go to the bathroom, thereby validating the question.  I edited my answer anyways, though, because I agree that it is rather redundant in that form.

Comment: Though the student may face disciplinary action, they are still _able_ to go without permission.

Comment: Not if _not_ facing disciplinary action was a requirement of the student.  The student was not _able_ to go to the bathroom without facing disciplinary action.  Look at [definition four](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/able):  "legally empowered, qualified, or authorized."  The student was unauthorized to go to the bathroom and thus unable to go.

Comment: @z7sg:  They are _physically_ able to go but not _rightfully_ able to go.  (they don't have permission)

Comment: That's not what I mean by able.

Answer (score 2):

It matters who your audience is.  What your words mean to the members of your audience and how they sound to them is more important than what a grammarian says (unless he/she is part of your audience ;).  If "may" would sound unnecessarily snobbish, use "can".  If "can" would get you the response "Of course you can; do you mean '*may* I'?", use "may".

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the reference to Shakespeare, I can add that in German the situation with can/may is exactly the same. But seeing that: If you ask a question like: Can I go to the toilette? Then well who will ask himself in front of others if he/she has the ability to go to the toilette, so there is really no ambiguity here